# What does the developper do in speed warp?

Tags: speed-warp

As the title states,I'm wondering what the developper does in speed warp. I've tried the way i HEARD you beat The Game (after developper boss) but that doesn't work.
by the way i heard it was (code at bottom of page). Anyways,How do you defeat it? i can't move,attack,and barely even defend myself!!! i DO know it is possible,but HOW?

> ↑↑↓↓←→←→ B A

Comment: This question appears to be off topic because it is about developer inten-- wait... Nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

The developper munges your keyboard, but is otherwise a standard boss fight.

Work out the key mapping ASAP by trying every key on the keyboard (it's random every time). Once you've worked it out, just fight as normal.

Answer (score 1):

I personally used a strength potion at the start of every round and then tried to find the ranged attack key, I then spammed health potions/ the ranged attack and just hoped I would win